# Stuck in MVC4 while following MVC3 tutorial for MVCmusicstore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following [MVC 3 music store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) for MVC in MVC4 and have gotten stuck . Everything went well until I came in the stage where I used the `Sampledata.cs` from `MVCmusicstore-Assets` and made some changes in `Global.ascx.cs` as instructed in the tutorial. Now the error appears in `SampleData.cs` which says:

> "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'  "and  "Operator
>   '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'"

With my lack of experience in MVC, I could not figure out where I made some simple and blunder mistake or there is something to be taken care of while doing mvc3 projects tutorial in mvc4.

I look forward for your reply.

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: The error says it all - somewhere in the code you're trying to compare an int and a string.  Without any indication of where this is happening, I can't really offer more help than that!

Comment: Most of us don't have the music store tutorial available.  Can you show the line of code that won't compile?  Maybe the whole method?

Comment: It's not an mvc issue, it's a c#.  C# is a strongly typed language.  You need to parse the string into an integer you can't just assign it.